# Is there a way to pass data from a page graphql call to a component graphql call?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I am trying to pass data (contentful_id) to a component graphql call. Is this possible? I am using gatsby.

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query pageQuery($slug: String!){
        contentfulPage(slug: {eq: $slug}){
            content {
                ... on ContentfulPersonBar {
                  contentful_id: contentful_id
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to pass that contentful_id into the below query.

```
export const personBarQuery = graphql`
    query personBarQuery($contentful_id: String!){
        contentfulPersonBar(contentful_id: {eq: $contentful_id}){
            heading
            people{
                etc
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this during runtime (after build). In `createPages` hook  at some point you have `$slug` resolved. Additional queries can be performed there to get you `$contentful_id` variable and pass it down to page context, same way you do for `$slug`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can pass in props into a graphql query?